# Properly using consensus/ethash module in go-ethereum

Tags: golang, mining-pools, ethash

Traditionally, Ethereum pools used the deprecated [Ethash](https://github.com/ethereum/ethash), which is quite inconvenient to use with modern golang, specifically around the usage of Go modules. Examples of this are [Sammy007's Open Ethereum Pool](https://github.com/sammy007/open-ethereum-pool/blob/bcfc0eb0e683993ad0c51bacad8d4b354e769393/proxy/miner.go#L28-L48) and [Etherchain.org's example pool](https://github.com/etherchain-org/ethpool-core/blob/8038b967e365bbf56ef8c41583ed626c999e1013/pool.go#L189-L207).

That being said, these are both from four or five years ago. It is now recommended to use the `consensus/ethash` module within the main [Geth repo](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum), as specified [here](https://github.com/ethereum/ethash/issues/94#issuecomment-292498425).

So as a pool operator looking to operate a high performance pool, how can you use the `consensus/ethash` module without wasting a large amount of I/O? The main inconvenience I see is that the [`VerifyHeader`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/ethash#Ethash.VerifyHeader) function replaces the old "Verify" function, but its dependent upon the [`ChainHeaderReader`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum@v1.10.4/consensus#ChainHeaderReader) function.

Putting aside having to either wrap the corresponding RPC calls in the object or caching the block data (to avoid I/O), the real issue I see is that you'll only ever be able to verify a block based off of the network difficulty (i.e. there is no good way to check a block based off of the pool's difficulty, not the network difficulty).

It definitely is possible to then create some hacky `ChainHeaderReader` implementation that allows you to inject a fake difficulty into the Parent that is returned from the `GetHeader` function [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/4fcc93d9229e99b14d3d1500f05ada6ba1f789bb/consensus/ethash/consensus.go#L105), but it just seems like this is jumping through hoops to use the modern version of Ethash (as a pool operator). Is there anything I'm missing about how this should be done?

Comment: It seems like what I'm really looking for is the [`verifySeal`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/d8ff53dfb8a516f47db37dbc7fd7ad18a1e8a125/consensus/ethash/sealer.go#L420) method, but it isn't exported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this alternative implementation [etclabscore/go-etchash](https://github.com/etclabscore/go-etchash). I'm unsure about performance, but it seems to fit the bill (with no go modules issues and without `cgo`), and since the only difference between Ethash and Etchash is the [epoch length](https://ecips.ethereumclassic.org/ECIPs/ecip-1099) there shouldn't be any problems.